# How to create an array like this

Tags: python, arrays

I'm building a correlation matrix for twenty bonds and need to create an array like the following and would like to know how I can create such an array using a loop.

```
 [[1],
 [0.3, 1],
 [0.3, 0.3, 1],
 [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1],
 [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1],
 [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1],
 [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1],
 [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1],
 [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1],
 [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1],
 [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1],
 [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get it with the following:

```
[[0.3 for x in range(y)] + [1] for y in range(20)]
```

or equivalently, by:

```
[[0.3] * y + [1] for y in range(20)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here an expanded version of the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


def generate_stepped_list(steps, last_number, repeated_number):
    """
    " @return a list (of `steps` length) of lists where each inner list is
    " one time longer than the previous one.
    " Lines are padded with repeated_number until the last position with
    " contains the last_number.
    " [[last_number],                                            -
    "  [repeated_number, last_number],                           ^
    "  [repeated_number, repeated_number, last_number]           | steps
    "   ...                                                      |
    "  [repeated_number, ... , repeated_number, last_number]]    -
    """
    stepped_list = []
    for i in range(steps):
        step = [repeated_number for x in range(i)]
        step.append(last_number)
        stepped_list.append(step)

    return stepped_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stepped_list_12 = generate_stepped_list(12, 1, 0.3)
    print(stepped_list_12)
```

Here the code compressed using list comprehensions (same as @dcg which is right).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


def generate_stepped_list(steps, last_number, repeated_number):
    return [[repeated_number] * y + [last_number,] for y in range(steps)]

if __name__ == "__main__":                       
    stepped_list_12 = generate_stepped_list(12, 1, 0.3)        
    print(stepped_list_12)
```

Answer (score -1):

The pattern you want can be done with the help of the nested loop:-

```
pattern = []  # Creating list to store pattern by append method in list.
for x in range(12):        
     start = [1]
     for y in range(x):
         start = start + [0.3]
     pattern.append(start)
print(pattern)
for var in pattern:
    print(var)
```

Comment: That edit fixed about half of what was wrong with your code before. The edited code still does not work properly. Even if it did work properly it could still be deleted by reviewers because you did not include an explanation of how the code works. I see code without an explanation deleted by reviewers every day, because code without an explanation doesn't help readers enough to understand what the code does.

Comment: @karel ok let me add explanation.